# Variance of a product of Bernoulli with another distribution

Tags: probability, self-study, variance, bernoulli-distribution

I have a distribution X, now I play the following game:
I toss a coin, if it falls on a head, I get nothing, if it falls on tails, I get a prize drawn from X distribution. I play the game N times.

My outcome Y is therefore the sum of the products of iid Bernoulli variables with iid X.

I need to find the variance of that outcome.

EDIT:
ok. point made with regard to this question being a textbook one. so to elaborate just a bit - I want to try to express the variance in terms of the distribution of X and the observed outcome of Y, avoiding the use of p and N which I know little about.

for example if X is a constant (let's say 1), and p is very small, then the obvious variance is:
N*p(1-p)
but N*p is approximately Y and (1-p) is close to 1 (under the assumptions that p is small), and hence the variance is approximately Y.

I try to find similar expression for a more general X. I can make the assumption the p is small, and that X looks like a poisson variable, but I need the variance in terms of Y and X and without p and N.

Comment: This appears to be a routine bookwork question. Please add the `self-study` tag and read its [tag-wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info), modifying your question as suggested there -- specifically giving details of your attempt and where you struck trouble.

Comment: Hint 1: consider the variance of playing the game once. Then consider the variance of N plays of the game.

Comment: thanks for the comments, see the edits inside the question

Comment: Please add the `self-study` tag and if you haven't yet done so, read its [tag-wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info), (etc). If you don't know how to add the tag, I can explain.

Comment: I don't think you're going to be able to avoid at least dealing with $Np$ and even then you're stuck with an approximation. Is $N$ very large? (many times larger than 1/p, say?)

Comment: yes. you can assume that N is very large and p is very small and that N>>1/p

Comment: amit -- Is Np known?

Comment: Are you trying to **estimate** the variance?  (If you want to **calculate** it, then the answer must involve $N$ and $p$ somehow, for the simple reason that changing those parameters leads to a **different** variance)

Comment: If you have the observed $Y$ you could just calculate the sample variance of it directly. You should clarify the question further. What is known and what exactly is it you want to achieve?

Comment: obviously I want an estimate based on data I observe/know about.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a rough outline of an approach, with some comments.

Let $Z_i\sim \text{Bernoulli}(p)$

Let $X_i\sim F_X$

Let $Y_i=X_iZ_i$. From your setup (coin toss for $Z_i$), $X_i$ and $Z_i$ are presumably independent.

Hence we can compute $E(X_iZ_i)$ easily.

Note that $Z_i^2=Z_i$ (!). Hence $E(Y_i^2)=E(X_i^2Z_i^2)=E(X_i^2Z_i)$.

Again we can use independence to simplify and from those get a simple expression for $\text{Var}(Y_i)$

This expression definitely involves $p$!

Then the sum of $N$ such terms involves $N$.

If you know $Np$ you can take that out as a factor, leaving you with a sum of two terms. One of those terms has a $p$ in it, for which you might be prepared to say the multiplicative term involving $p$ is close to but less than 1, leading to an upper bound on the variance which is a multiple of $Np$.

More details in the question might lead to more suggestions.

Comment: thanks. I got that far, but hoped someone would have a brilliant idea to take me one step further.

Comment: Since this is a self-study question, you won't get a complete answer. If you tell a teacher "I don't understand" you will always get the return quesiton "What is it that you don't understand" and the same happens here. So, what is preventing you from taking one step further? Maybe it is easier to formulate that if you start with telling us what you have tried.

Comment: @amit There's lots of useful hints there. Where do you have trouble?

Comment: in fact it is not really a self study. I am working with a somewhat flawed "AB-testing" platform that only records successes, on A and B, but not the total attempts on A and B. I can assume that traffic is equally distributed between the two arms. but all I can observe is successes on A and successes on B. I know that success rates in both A and B are rather small.

Comment: Are you saying you're aiming to perform some kind of hypothesis test? That's rather a different problem. If that's the case, you should probably ask a new question.